# Checking whether the text in a JTextField is a certain data type

Tags: java, validation, user-interface, input

I am trying to write some validation code in my class for my GUI. How would I go about getting the text from a JTextField into a while statement and prompting a JOptionPane for the user to enter the necessary number(double)? To be more specific, how do I check if what I got from the JTextField is a string/string+number/anything other than a number?

```
String text=JTextField.getText();

while(text.equals*a string or anything but a number*);
   JOP("Invalid input ............ etc...
```

If you have time, here is my GUI and my class. I am trying to do this for the rest of the methods. But the answer to the above will suffice.

http://www.mediafire.com/?f079i1xtihypg1b

http://www.mediafire.com/file/f079i1xtihypg1b/FinanceGUI.java

#### Update:

This is what I have so far:

```
  //get the text entered in the amountRentText
  //JTextField and parse it to a Double
String amtRentIn=amountRentText.getText();

try{Double.parseDouble(amtRentIn);}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
   while()
       amtRentIn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid input. Please "+
           "enter your rent: ");
 }

 double rent= Double.parseDouble(amtRentIn);
 fin.setRent(rent);
```

What do I put in the while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String amtRentIn=amountRentText.getText();
boolean incorrect = true;
while(incorrect){
try{Double.parseDouble(amtRentIn);incorrect = false;}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
   amtRentIn=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid input. Please "+
           "enter your rent: ");
 }

}
```

Comment: I actually replaced incorrect= true with return; and just asked the user to change what was wrong in the JTextField. How does this incorrect=true work though?

Comment: @Andrei TheGiant Haxtor you are right. The last incorrect=true is not necessary I have deleted it and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`javax.swing.InputVerifier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) is designed for this. Your implementation of `verify()` could invoke `parseDuble()`. Here's another [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/InputVerifierExample.htm).

Answer (score 0):

A "cheap" not too beautiful solution that occurs to me would be using the Double.parseDouble(..) on that string, and being ready to catch the parsing exception that would occur in the event the String had any non-numeric content.

Comment: ehm... I am a java noob in my first class, and this is my final project. I dont know much about catching exceptions.

Comment: If you're looking or a simple test, then as stated: try{Double.parseDouble(yourTextHere)}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){/* not a double */}

Comment: ok, so where would I prompt the user through JOptionPane to enter the correct number? In the try{ --- } ?

Comment: It depends. You can do in multiple ways. The important in this case is that the code that can throw this exception is inside the try {} catch block. So, even if you collect the user's input as a string, the important for this is that you do the parsing inside a try catch block. The rest could be outside. Also, inside the catch block, you must put the code that you want to execute in case that the parsing fails due to a non-numeric input from the user.